# TabLayout + ViewPager - ViewPager is clipping TabLayout elevation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have bottom `TabLayout` which is connected to `ViewPager` above. `TabLayout` has top `elevation` which should be visible in front of ViewPager (want to have cool elevation fade out effect at the bottom of each `ViewPager` page). Same should be applied to any content in that `ViewPager`. Problem is, that this elevation is somehow clipped and I cant see it in my app at all. `ViewPager` pages are also opening bottom sheets, so I want to have same effect that `BottomSheet` is peeking from behind of `TabLayout`.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/paper_transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <components.NonSwipableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabLayout"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

    </components.NonSwipableViewPager>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        style="@style/main_tab">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/main_tab_layout" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/main_tab_layout"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="main_tab">
        <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/padding_large</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/padding_small</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/padding_medium</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/paper_transparent</item>
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
        <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
        <item name="tabIconTint">@color/tab_icon_tint</item>
        <item name="tabIndicator">@drawable/tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/tab_color</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorGravity">center</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorFullWidth">false</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">50dp</item>
        <item name="tabRippleColor">@null</item>
    </style>
```